# How to set Excel print page margins when using JRParameter.IS_IGNORE_PAGINATION

Tags: java, jasper-reports

How to set Excel print page margins when using `JRParameter.IS_IGNORE_PAGINATION`?

My Jasper-Report contains a header and a table with many rows. It is created with the setting `JRParameter.IS_IGNORE_PAGINATION` ...

```
    params.put(JRParameter.IS_IGNORE_PAGINATION, Boolean.TRUE);
    return JasperFillManager.fillReport(inputStream, params, new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(myDtoList));
```

... and then exported via `JRXlsExporter`.

The result is how I want it - an Excel sheet with one heading and a table without any margins or headings in between.

But when printing the sheet, there are no margins on the paper. The table starts right at the top edge.

How to set the margins for printing in this case?

EDIT: the setting of `JasperPrint.setTopMargin`, `JasperPrint.setBottomMargin` seems to be ignored by Jasper in this special case.

Comment: There is a set of print margin properties that can be used for the Excel export. See http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html#net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.print.page.bottom.margin for reference.

Comment: @shertage Yes, you're right! I will describe your solution in a seperate answer to my question. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comment of @shertage, here's the solution:

```
SimpleXlsReportConfiguration configuration = new SimpleXlsReportConfiguration();
configuration.setPrintPageBottomMargin(20);
configuration.setPrintPageBottomMargin(20);

JRXlsExporter exporterXLS = new JRXlsExporter();
...
exporterXLS.setConfiguration(configuration);
exporterXLS.exportReport();
```

In this special case the point is, to use `SimpleXlsReportConfiguration.setPrintPageTopMargin`, ... instead of  `JasperPrint.setTopMargin`, ... .

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand that once you take an export of your report, jasper server no longer has control over the exported file. So ideally you should try to set the page margin before calling export.

You can set the page margins on [JasperDesign](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/design/JasperDesign.html) object (before compiling it) or on the [JasperPrint](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JasperPrint.html) object using *setLeftMargin*, *setRightMargin*,  *setTopMargin*, *setBottomMargin*  methods.

Code sample with JasperPrint:

```
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(inputStream, params, new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(myDtoList));
jasperPrint.setLeftMargin(20);
jasperPrint.setRightMargin(20);
jasperPrint.setTopMargin(20);
jasperPrint.setBottomMargin(20);
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, stream);
exporter.exportReport();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer - but when filling the report with parameter `IS_IGNORE_PAGINATION` these margin settings are ignored by Jasper.